# ajax async used instead of rxjs async

Tags: angular, rxjs, async.js, ngrx

I'm introducing NgRx into my Angular 2 application. I'm using async for certain operations. However, somehow, the wrong async (I think the one for AjaxRequest) is being triggered which results in my Observables being triggered before they are set.

For instance: I'm receiving my translations through a webservice. I use a pipe to translate it to the correct text like so:

```
transform(value: string, args: any[]): any {
return this.uiMessages$
  .switchMap((uiMessages: UiMessage[]) => Observable.from(uiMessages))
  .find((uiMessage: UiMessage) => (uiMessage.key === value))
  .map((uiMessage: UiMessage) => uiMessage.translation);
```

}

In my component, I use the pipe like so:

```
<span class="user-welcome">{{'ui.main.welcome' | translate | async }} {{fullName}}</span>
```

The pipe is being triggered before my uiMessages Obeservable is set.

Do I have to import async explicitly or is there something else that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So where do you set `uiMessages`?

Comment: in my MessageReducer. `return [...action.payload.uiMessages];` When my application loads, the application container calls a method that retrieves the messages from a rest service. On receiving them, I dispatch an action to set all messages: `this.store.dispatch(new SetAllUiMessages(bootstrapInfo.uiMessages));`

Comment: I think he meant: In your `translate`-pipe, where/when is `uiMessages$` set or injected and not how it is populated with data ;)